# Parse a server side text file in javascript for a date then display text on another line the file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm under-skilled in my web programming skills but nonetheless, I'm trying to create a simple page that displays the next school workshop from a TXT file that is stored on the web server.  The TXT file is plaintext and lists:

```
the presenter
Day of the week, Date time the workshop is occurring
Room
Workshop title
```

The text file repeats these same 4 fields but with unique data and it goes down chronologically like below:

```
Elisabeth Oliver
Wed, Feb 13 from 9:00am-10:00am
808A
Reading for Understanding: How to Get the Most Out of Your Textbook
Allie Vernon
Thur, Feb 14 from 2:30pm-3:30pm
808A
Time Management and Achieving Personal Success
Jayley Lee
Tues, Feb 19 from 10:00am-11:30am
808A
Got Grit? Developing an Attitude for Success
```

I'm trying to create a page that checks the current system date/time and then runs down this text file looking for the next workshop coming up.

I have a working page that gets the current time and displays the next workshop from a hard coded list of variables, but I'd really like to just have the javascript read the workshop TXT file since that is my source.  Below is my old code

I'm using moment.js to perform time calculations.

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 

var d = new Date() 
var month = d.getMonth();
var dayofmonth = d.getDate();
var day = d.getDay(); 
var time = d.getHours(); 
var mins = d.getMinutes();
var year = d.getFullYear();

var d1 = new Date("February 13, 2019 9:00:00");
var d2 = new Date("February 14, 2019 14:30:00");
var d3 = new Date("February 19, 2019 10:00:00");

// Options for formatting the dates & Time
var options = {
    weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long",
    day: "numeric"
};


// Array for displaying workshop into
// Workshop[date variable holding date of workshop and start time, legnth of workshop in hours, title of workshop, presenter]
var Workshop1 = [d1, 1, "Reading for Understanding: How to Get the Most Out of Your Textbook", "Elisabeth Oliver"];
var Workshop2 = [d2, 1, "Time Management and Achieving Personal Success", "Allie Vernon"];
var Workshop3 = [d3, 1.5, "Got Grit? Developing an Attitude for Success", "Jayley Lee"];

// HTML to display current workshop info on Screen
function SetDivContent() 
{
    var div=document.getElementById('date_dependent');


    if (d.getTime() <= Workshop1[0]) { // Workshop 1
            div.innerHTML=Workshop1[2] + '<br>Presented by: ' + Workshop1[3] + '<br>' + d1.toLocaleDateString("en", options) + '<br>From: ' + moment(d1).format("h:mm A") + ' - ' + moment(moment(d1).add(Workshop1[1],"h")).format("h:mm A") + '<br>Room: 808A';
        }
        else if (d.getTime() <= d2) 
    { // Workshop 2
            div.innerHTML=Workshop2[2] + '<br>Presented by: ' + Workshop2[3] + '<br>' + d2.toLocaleDateString("en", options) + '<br>From: ' + moment(d2).format("h:mm A") + ' - ' + moment(moment(d2).add(Workshop2[1],"h")).format("h:mm A") + '<br>Room: 808A';
        }
        else if (d.getTime() <= d3) { // Workshop 3
            div.innerHTML=Workshop3[2] + '<br>Presented by: ' + Workshop3[3] + '<br>' + d3.toLocaleDateString("en", options) + '<br>From: ' + moment(d3).format("h:mm A") + ' - ' + moment(moment(d3).add(Workshop3[1],"h")).format("h:mm A") + '<br>Room: 808A';
        }

}
```

If today were February 14 at 9am the page would display:

```
Time Management and Achieving Personal Success
Presented By: Allie Vernon
From: 2:30pm - 3:30pm
Room: 808A
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish such magic?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files are in the same directory.

- index.html
- textfile.txt

Example, in your `textfile.txt`.

```
Hello World
```

Then in your `index.html`.

```
<script>
  function readTextFile() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", "textfile.txt", true);
    request.send();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( request.readyState !== 4 ) return;

        if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) resolve(request.responseText)
        else reject({
          status: request.status,
          statusText: request.statusText
        });
      };
    });
  }

  readTextFile().then((response) => console.log(response)); // THIS WILL LOG "Hello World" IN THE CONSOLE
</script>
```

This is just a solution for a part of your problem. You can use this as a start.